# Read/Write same MTLTexture on iOS

Tags: ios, metal

The `texture2d` `access::read_write` qualifier seems only available on OSX. Is there a way to read/write the same texture inside a `kernel` (or other) metal function?

The reason is the written texture values may not be final and can be updated by other threads.

Comment: You might be able to use a buffer in the `device` address space, combined with atomic functions, for this, but there are numerous caveats (buffer must be of `int` or `uint` type; weak memory order guarantees; possible performance degradation if contention arises). What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I need to compute a stroke width, so a pixel can be updated multiple times, but only the one with the lower value should be stored (so I need to read the previous value back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint @warrenm. It works using an atomic buffer

```
device atomic_uint *buf [[ buffer(0) ]]
```

performing following steps:

1. I initialize my atomic buffer in a separate `kernel` function that runs before the operation
2. The next `kernel` computes a min value for a specific coordinate using `atomic_fetch_min_explicit(buf[pos], val, memory_order_relaxed)`